# Why aren't timers working in fullscreen mode?

Tags: c#, winforms, timer, keyboard, global

I got a windows form application with a timer.

Whenever I open a fullscreen application like a game and try to debug the timer, it completely ignores it. But the second I change the application to window mode, the debugging works.

I also tried pressing a key (using global hook) and debugging the click and the debugging worked while I was in the game (full screen).

Has anyone ever had this issue? how can it be fixed?

EDIT : It seems that even this doesn't go into debug  (Called OpenNewTempThread from Form1())

```
private void OpenNewTempThread()
    {
        Thread thread = new Thread(Temp) { Name = "TempThread" };
        thread.Start();
    }

    private bool Temping = true;
    private void Temp()
    {
        while (true)
        {
            while (Temping)
            {
                Thread.Sleep(5000);
            }
            Thread.Sleep(100);
        }
    }
```

Comment: Please clarify your question. I.e. "it completely ignores it" is hard to understand.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Try putting this line in your code (it'll work assuming you are running under a debugger):

```
System.Diagnostics.Debugger.Break();
```